# Django REST:is invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using the [REST Framework](http://django-rest-framework.org), when making a POST I get the following error...

```
TypeError at /api/profiles/
'attribute_answers' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

PUT seems to work without any issues.

**Serializer**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='username')
    attribute_answers = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        depth = 2
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'active', 'type', 'user', 'attribute_answers')

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        """
        Create or update a new snippet instance.

        """
        if instance:
            # Update existing instance
            instance.name = attrs.get('name', instance.name)
            instance.active = attrs.get('active', instance.active)
            instance.type = attrs.get('type', instance.type)
            instance.attribute_answers = attrs.get('attribute_answers', instance.attribute_answers)
            return instance

        # Create new instance
        return Profile(**attrs)
```

Comment: I suspect because when you `POST`, you are creating a new item and you don't have a related field yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `restore_object` method is incorrectly attempting to pass `attribute_answers` to the `Profile` constructor.

As it happens, since you're using `ModelSerializer` you don't need that `restore_object` method at all - the model instance restore will be handled for you.  The `restore_object` method is only required for basic `Serializer` classes.